# Как применить text-overflow?

Tags: css

Сейчас `text-overflow` применяется к `.product`, т.к только этот элемент имеет ограничения по ширине. Соответственно текст обрезается, но без подстановки троеточия в конец. Требуется обрезать текст, который по ширине больше, чем `.into` и подставить троеточие в конце. Проблема в том, что `.into` не имеет ограничения по ширине. Плюс, применить `text-overflow` нужно к внутренним тегам `<p>`. Есть идеи?

```css
.catalog {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 15px;
    grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

.product {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.info {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.info .name {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.info > .name,
.info > .price {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="info">
            <p class="name">Наименование</p>
            <p class="price">456 руб.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```css
.catalog {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

.product {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.info .name {
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.info>.name,
.info>.price {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="info">
      <p class="name">НаименованиеОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекстОченьДлинныйТекст</p>
      <p class="price">456 руб.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это именно то, чего я добивался. Зачем дописывать width: 100% если и без этого работает? Могут быть проблемы в разных браузерах или что? Мне очень важно чтобы на старых мобильных телефонах работало.

Comment: без width:100% могут быть проблемы с изображением, которое МЕНЬШЕ предназначенного для него места. а насчет работоспособности в разных старых браузерах - проверьте это свойство на caniuse.com